# Binding Listbox Item Template to Variable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

So I'm entering Items into the listbox with this C# code:

```
     void GetItems() {
     VideoListBox.ItemsSource = from list1 in xmlfeedresult.Descendants("video")
                                   select new VideoItem
                                   {
                                       Username = list1.Element("u").Value,
                                       Thumbnail = list1.Element("i").Value,
                                       Description = list1.Element("d").Value
                                   };

    }

    public class VideoItem
    {
        public string Username;
        public string Thumbnail;
        public string Description;
    }
```

And  this is the XAML code which is used

```
<ListBox Height="588" Margin="272,101,272,0" Name="VideoListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail }" Height="300" Width="500" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,8,0"/>
                    <StackPanel Width="370">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Username}" Foreground="#FFC8AB14" FontSize="28" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The problem is that it is generating three items in the listbox, but values in Username, Thumbnail and Description aren't showing up. Its just three completely black items. 
Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your values should be public **properties**, not just fields.

```
public class VideoItem
{
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public string Thumbnail {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```